# Android JUnit test blocks indefinitely when Observable observed on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-testing, kotlin

I'm writing a simple test that is equivalent to:

```
Test fun testObservable() {
    val returnedObservable = Observable.create(object : Observable.OnSubscribe<String> {
        override fun call(t: Subscriber<in String>) {
            t.onNext("hello")
            t.onCompleted()
        }

    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

    val result = returnedObservable.toBlocking().first()
    assertEquals("hello", result)
}
```

The test blocks indefinitely on `returnedObservable.toBlocking().first()` when `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` is present.

Is there a way to transform the observable to return the result?

The `returnedObservable` is returned from method call with .subscribeOn and .observeOn already applied so removing those is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is a bug mentioned here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/50

btw why don't you use [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin)?

You example will look much better:

```
    val returnedObservable = observable<String> { subscriber ->
        subscriber.onNext("hello")
        subscriber.onCompleted()
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedules.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: I tend to reduce the number of dependencies needed to answer my question ie make it readable for non-kotlin programmers.